# Laravel excel, why function($reader) cannot get variables?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5.4

Currently im using Laravel-Excel(MaatWebsite). I have codes like this in controller

```
public function house($id)
{
  $furniture_number = Furniture::where('id', $id)->first();

  $rows = Excel::load('storage\\app\\public\\upload\\furniture.xlsx', function($reader)
  {
    $reader->noHeading(); 
    $reader->takeColumns($furniture_number->amount);
  })->get();
}
```

The dd($furniture_number->amount) return "10"

Undefined variable: furniture_number (at the $reader->takeColumns($furniture_number->amount); line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the $furniture_number variable to the closure with the 'use' statement:

```
  $rows = Excel::load('storage\\app\\public\\upload\\furniture.xlsx', function($reader) use ($furniture_number) {
    $reader->noHeading(); 
    $reader->takeColumns($furniture_number->amount);
  })->get();
```

Comment: what if there is another variable that i wanted to take? let say i wanted both $furniture_number and $anothervariable

Comment: use ($furniture_number, $another_variable, $third_variable)

Comment: Or first, put all of those variables into an array:  $variables = compact('furniture_number', 'another_variable', 'third_variable');